# Can't take photo while recording a video only if camera is unlock() for record

Tags: android, android-activity, video, camera

I am developing an App that can record videos, take photos and during recording video you can take photos. For simple recording video and taking photos I have no problems. The problem is when I start a video record and I try to `camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);`. **On some devices** it never goes to `public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){}` on my `PictureCallback jpegCallback`. I have tested many hours and stackoverflow is my last hope to solve the issue.

Early in the code in my `VideoRecordActivity` in `surfaceChanged()` I open and set the camera like this:

```
  camera = Camera.open();

  Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
  p.setPreviewSize(camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth, camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);
  p.setPreviewFrameRate(camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate);

  camera.setParameters(p);
  camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
  camera.startPreview();
```

After that I am preparing the `MediaRecorder` like this(I am unlocking the camera here, because after the record is done I reconnect the camera with `camera.reconnect()` and I call `prepareRecorder()` again and I can start to record the next video):

```
  private void prepareRecorder() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    camera.unlock();
    recorder.setCamera(camera);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
  }
```

I can't record a video if my `camera.unlock()` is not called before `recorder.setCamera(camera);`. But on some devices if I try to `takePicture()` during recording a video and after this `camera.unlock()` it never calls the overrided `public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)`. If I just only comment the `camera.unlock()` and never start recording a video in first place and just tab on the visible takePhoto Button it is working and taking photos as usual. **Any ideas why I can't take photos *on some devices* after starting a video record and unlock()-ing the camera?**

I have tested this on Android 4.4.2 - Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10" and 7". On the 7" I can take photos during video recording, but on the 10" it can't. Any ideas? Regards, Vlad.

Comment: Have you found any solution for your case?