# Android capture photo while recording a video. Issue with unlock() of Camera

Tags: android, android-activity, video, camera

I have developed an Android App that can take photos, record videos and take photos while recording video. To record a video before the `recorder.setCamera()` I have to unlock the camera `camera.unlock()`.

After that the recording starts and everything is fine. I have a button that is visible after that and if I tab on it the camera is taking picture `camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);`.

After that an Async response is coming in the overrided `onPictureTaken()` method of `PictureCallback jpegCallback` and everything seems legit, but only on some devices.

**Does anyone have idea why I can't take photo while recording a video with unlock()-ed camera.**

---

For more information you can see my detailed question here:

[Can't take photo while recording a video only if camera is unlock() for record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022836/cant-take-photo-while-recording-a-video-only-if-camera-is-unlock-for-record)

Answer (score -1):

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // if(v == myButton)
    // {
    if (recording) {
        // stop recording and release camera
        // type.setVisibility(View.GONE);1
        type.setText("");
        myChronometer.stop();
        myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        // mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
        releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
        //
        myCamera.lock();
        recording = false;

        // "/sdcard/fivo_flim/" + "fivo_flim_"+video_no
        // + ".mp4";


        System.out.println("11111111111   "+SessionManager.getVideoCount(prefs1));

        new UploadPicture(VideoScreen.this, mApi, "/", new File(
                "/sdcard/record/" + "record"
                        + SessionManager.getVideoCount(prefs1) + ".mp4"))
                .execute();
        SessionManager.saveVideoCount(prefs1,
                SessionManager.getVideoCount(prefs1) + 1);

        mWakeLock.release();
        System.out.println("uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu");
    } else {
        // Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
        releaseCamera();
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    VideoScreen.this,
                    "Fail in PrepareCamera()!\n         \n   Please Insert SD Card or\n   Restart your phone ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        System.out.println("prepare media recorder");
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Starting Media Recorder");
        try {
            mediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("exception is " + e);
        }
        type.setText("Recording...");

        myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        myChronometer.start();

        recording = true;
        myButton.setClickable(false);
        try {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myButton.setClickable(true);
                }
            }, 3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SdCardPath" })
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/record/");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Logger.Debug("failed to create directory");
        }
    }


    video_no=SessionManager.getVideoCount(prefs1);


    mFiles.add("/sdcard/record/" + "record" + video_no
            + ".mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/record/" + "record"
            + video_no + ".mp4");
    video_no++;

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
            .getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        mediaRecorder = null;
        myCamera.lock();

    }
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (myCamera != null) {
        myCamera.release();
        myCamera = null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Does this support zoom-In/Out feature while recording?